# html form add some javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to add javascript in my html form modal.
but i got error "uncaught referenceError: $ is not defined" when i define count variable.

So ,how can i resolve this question.

```html
<div class="modal">
    <form id="multiform">
        <script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="/static/js/jquery.min.js">
            var count=$('select#ip option:selected').length;
            alert(count);
            /*code more*/ 
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 mistakes

- Use `src` instead of `href`.
- Once you have given `src` to a `script` tag, then script inside that tag will be **ignored**.
- Keep it outside `body` tag or in `head` tag.

**Demo**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
  <form id="multiform">
  </form>
</div>
<script>
  var count = $('select#ip option:selected').length;
  alert(count);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you are using href insted of src

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
    <form id="multiform">
        <script  type="text/javascript">
            var count=$('select#ip option:selected').length;
            alert(count);
            /*code more*/ 
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
```